# How to branch SQL query statement using conditions?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say we have table `customer` with column `subject_type_fk`. We need to find name of the customer which can be in table `person` or `enterprise`. `subject_type_fk` defines which of those 2 tables search in. `subject_type_fk` can be 0 or 1. `subject_fk` defines the primary key of record from `person` or `enterprise`. Both tables have `name` column we need to retrieve (actually `enterprise.enterprise` and `person.last_name`). `Customer.customer` is given as input parameter. How to write that kind of query for postgreSQL?

---

UPDATE

[image]

Comment: can you post the table definitions?

Comment: Personally I would combine all the fields of the tables `Customer`, `Person`, and `Enterprise` in one table. Then use the `subject_type_fk` to determine which fields I read.

Comment: @Tony, can you provide you version of query?

Comment: @RCola - At the moment your model is not very "relational"; as you have found it's not possible to create a conditional relationship between tables. To relate your tables decide if the more important thing about a customer is the person or the enterprise. You could have: a `customer` is a `person` belonging to an `enterprise`; or, if all your customers are businesses, have: a `customer` is a `enterprise` with a contact who is a `person`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select p.last_name
from customer c join person p on c.subject_fk = p.person and c.subject_type_fk = 0
union    
select e.full_name
from customer c join enterprise e on c.subject_fk = e.enterprise and c.subject_type_fk = 1
```

(edited after OP's edit)